# How to record correctly a audio in format 16bits LittleEndian signed integer PCM with core audio

Tags: c, audio, core-audio, pcm, 16-bit

I know there are many potentially similar questions but my problem is very particular.
I'm relatively new using CoreAudio. I have a fully functional app in Linux / C and using the Alsa library. I am adapting it to MacOS / C but I have a problem to get the necessary audio format.
I configure the AudioQueue as follows:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription recordFormat;
memset(&recordFormat, 0, sizeof(recordFormat));
recordFormat.mFormatID |= kAudioFormatLinearPCM;

recordFormat.mFormatFlags &= ~kLinearPCMFormatFlagsAreAllClear;
recordFormat.mFormatFlags &= ~kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsFloat;
recordFormat.mFormatFlags |= kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;
recordFormat.mFormatFlags &= ~kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian;
recordFormat.mFormatFlags &= ~kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
recordFormat.mFormatFlags |= kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsNonMixable;
recordFormat.mFormatFlags &= ~kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;

recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
recordFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;

recordFormat.mSampleRate = 44100;
```

But the audio that I record has a problem:

- The frequency does not seem quite correct because when I open
  the .pcm file with audacity the sound are accelerated.

After reading "A Hands-On Guide to Audio Programming for Mac and iOS" and having searched both the network and all the recommended readings that I could, I have not found any reason why the supplied code is not good.

It's my first post so I apologize if I have not complied with all the rules. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `mFormatFlags` configuration is crazy looking. You want little endian 16bit? Wouldn't `mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger` do that? Maybe show how you're configuring the audio queue and how you're writing the pcm to disk.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman You're right, the problem was how to access the buffer to write it to disk. Well, I was accessing a memory address from a buffer that was of type "void *" in the following way: & inBuffer [toEnd]. I'm sorry to have bothered you so that in the end it was a problem of absurd coding. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

If the sound editor is playing raw audio twice as fast at twice the pitch, then it might be trying to play a mono file as if it were stereo.

Comment: thanks for idea. But the problem I had with the frequency was that I'm reading from a buffer of type void * configured as Integer as if they were short typer. Once this error has been corrected, the listening frequency is the same as that read from the file.